# B-Tree Revision

Tags: java, algorithm, mergesort, b-tree

If we are looking for line intersections (horizontal and vertical lines only) and we have n lines with half of them vertical and no intersections then

Sorting the list of line end points on y value will take N log N using mergesort

Each insert delete and search of our data structue (assuming its a b-tree) will be < log n

so the total search time will be N log N

What am i missing here, if the time to sort using mergesort takes a time of N log N and insert and delete takes a time of < log n are we dropping the constant factor to give an overal time of N log N. If not then how comes < log n goes missing in total ONotation run time?

Thanks

Comment: Um... what exactly are you doing? I don't see how inserting into and deleting from a b-tree has anything to do with a mergesort.

Comment: trying to find where lines intersect

Comment: @stan: yeah, so why do you need to insert and delete elements in a b-tree for that?

Comment: no idea, its just the way the teacher recomended doing it, i am not to sure tbh, hence why i am asking on here for revision help :D

the ones we practised with code i can remember easily, but these ones off of slides that we haven't practised are really hard to revise for, and i am probably not capable in a programming sence to replicate this problem in code, so i cant practise :S

Comment: @Michael: I am guessing but I suspect the question refers to detecting intersections between the line segments, and many intersection algorithms make use of B-trees.

Comment: @Adamski: if I understand the algorithm correctly, there is no explicit sorting, so asking about a combination of both makes no sense.

Comment: And it looks as though stan makes the common mistake of thinking that "B-Tree" is short for "binary search tree" - which is not true. B-Trees are much more complex data structures used for indexes that are too large to fit into memory.

Comment: i think i understand what a btree is , i have already written my notes on these, b-trees are for multiple nodes right? when one set of nodes gets full up it restructures, and when the root fills it restructures and adds a new layer of height?

Comment: adamski is correct by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big-O notation describes the asymptotic behavior of the algorithm.  That is, it describes the behavior of the algorithm as *N* trends towards infinity.  The portion of the algorithm that takes *N* log *N* time will dwarf the portion of the algorithm that takes log *N* time.  The significance of the log *N* portion diminishes to relatively nothing as *N* becomes large.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your tutor is referring to the problem of [Line Segment Intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_segment_intersection), which is more complex than simply sorting the segments.  You'll note that this article references the Shamos–Hoey algorithm, which uses a binary tree to store the line segments and efficiently detect intersections.

Michael is correct in that using a binary tree is pointless for a one-off sort of the line segments.  However, in the context of detecting intersections, sorting followed by a search will yield quadratic performance and is not the best approach, hence why line detection algorithms use binary trees.

For example, suppose you sort your line segments along the x-axis from left to right.  A naive detection algorithm would then be something like:

```
for (int i=0; i<segs.length - 1; ++i) {
  boolean searching = true;

  for (int j=i+1; j<segs.length && searching; ++j) {
     if (segments overlap on x-axis) {
       // Check for intersection.
     } else {
       // No overlap so terminate inner loop early.
       // This is the advantage of having a sorted list.
       searching = false;
     }
  }
}
```

Due to the doubly-nested loop the worst case is O(n^2) and occurs when all line segments overlap on the x-axis.  The best case is linear and occurs when none of the segments overlap on the x-axis.

You might want to start by implementing the naive algorithm followed by one that uses a B-tree structure.

Comment: The Wikipedia article mentions binary search trees, not B-Trees though.

Comment: Good point.  I made the same mistake of mentioning B-Tree when I meant binary tree - I'll edit my answer.